# Query for getting country name which has less then 3 city

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table named country and city that are relational table.

Table Structure :

```
Country : CountryID CountryName

City : CityID CountryID CityName
```

In which both table contain some data. i want result which country have less then 3 city.

Comment: Sometimes you can't have mysql and sql-server query that runs on both engine at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select c1.CountryName 
 from country c1 left join city c2 on c1.CountryID=c2.CountryID
 group by c2.CountryID,c1.CountryName,c1.CountryID having count(*)<3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select c.CountryID
from country c
left join city ci on c.CountryID=ci.CountryID
group by c.CountryID
having COUNT(c.CountryID)<3
```

Comment: inner join will skip countries without cities

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT co.CountryID, co.CountryName, COUNT(ci.CityID) as NumberOfCities
FROM Country co
LEFT JOIN City ci
ON
co.CountryID = ci.CountryID
GROUP BY co.CountryID, co.CountryName
HAVING COUNT(ci.CityID) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select * from country;

CNID CNNAME
--- ----------
ind india
pak pakistan
usa amerika

SQL> select * from city;

      CTID CNID CTNAME
---------- --- ----------
        11 ind delhi
        22 ind mummbai
        55 pak lahore
        66 pak islamabad
        77 pak peshavar
       100 usa ny
       101 usa ams
       102 usa chi
       103 usa amaz

9 rows selected.


SQL> with ans as
  2  (select cn.cnname, cn.cnid, count(ctid)
  3  from country cn, city ct
  4  where cn.cnid = ct.cnid
  5  group by cn.cnid, cn.cnname
  6  having count(ctid)<3)
  7  select cnname from ans;

CNNAME
----------
india

SQL>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?

Answer (score -2):

```
select * 
from country LEFT JOIN 
  (select CountryID, count(*) as cnt 
   from city 
   group by CountryID 
   having cnt<3) c ON country.CountryID =c.CountryID
```

Comment: Countries with 3 or more cities will show up in your query and also show a count as NULL